# Error SonarCloud with openjdk8 during pipeline gitlab-ci in java

Tags: java, maven, java-8, gitlab-ci, sonarcloud

I have a problem with Gitlab CI, Maven and SonarCloud.

I use the jdk 8 so I had to use `<sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version>true</sonar.scanner.force-deprecated-java-version>` to be able to use Sonar but however I still have an error!

[image: Error during pipeline run]

Gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
  GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

sonarcloud-check:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
  stage: test
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
```

Thank you for your reply